# Display Android Preferences in Different Units

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I've got an Android preference activity where the layout is connected directly to my peference key/value pairs, ex:

```
<EditTextPreference
     android:key="timeout"
     android:defaultValue="timeout"
     android:title="Timeout"
     android:summary="Timeout (ms)"
     android:dialogTitle="Timeout (ms)" />
```

I need to change this somehow so that the display function (and *only* the display) is in seconds. Theoretically I could change it so that the storage and retrivial of the value use seconds, but that happens far too often, so I dont want to change that if I can avoid it.

The activities/services that make up my app all pull directly from the Android preferences, ex:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
String s = settings.getString("timeout", ctx.getString(R.string.timeout));
```

So - what's the best way to change the display function for the preference, while still storing the values in milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, android is saving the value of a `EditTextPreference` using the [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) method. So you could use a custom View extending `EditTextPreference` and modify `setText()`.

Comment: Interesting ... if it works that will be a great trick! Give me a few hours and I'll report back

Comment: Your solution worked great. Just override setText (and getText) to change the value before it is saved/displayed. You also need to add onDefaultPreferenceSet (something to that effect) because that will call setText, and you don't want any adjustments in that case.